# Re-render problem when using react custom hook useLocalStorage in sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a custom hook to store some value in the localStorage and have an access to this value from any component in my React App. Also I want to make React App automatically re-render the component which is using the value from localStorage and show a new value.

So, I created a custom hook:

```
  export function useLocalStorageState(key, defaultState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    const storedState = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (storedState) {
      return JSON.parse(storedState);
    }
    return defaultState;
  });

  const setLocalStorageState = useCallback(
    (newState) => {
      const changed = state !== newState;
      if (!changed) {
        return;
      }
      setState(newState);
      if (newState === null) {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newState));
      }
    },
    [state, key]
  );

  return [state, setLocalStorageState];
}
```

I have React component Header, where I have a dropdown select with some values:

```
const Header = () => {
  const [numFormat, setNumFormat] = useLocalStorageState('numFormat');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setNumFormat(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }} size="small">
      <Select
        value={numFormat || 'myFormat'}
        label="Num format"
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <MenuItem value="decimal">Decimal</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="fractional">Fraction</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="impliedProbability">Probability %</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

And another React component which I want to re-render each time when I change the numFormat in Header:

```
const FormSettings = () => {
  const [numFormat] = useLocalStorageState('numFormat');
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(numFormat);
  }, [numFormat]);

  return (
    <h1>{numFormat}</h1>
)}
```

But there is a problem. When I change the numFormat in the Header nothing changes in the FormSettings.

Comment: In that case i do recommend using useContext it's really good to that kind of problem

Comment: Check out the useContext built in hook in React, it can be used for this exact purpose. https://haseebmajid.dev/blog/react-hooks-context-and-local-storage

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because, the custom hook instances are different in both components. You have called your custom hook in both components and both hooks have their own state. When you change state in first hook, it will not affect in second hook.

You have to pass `numFormat` from `Header` component to `FormSettings` component via props and use that value instead of instantiating new hook.

If you are not able to pass `numFormat` from `Header` to `FormSettings`, uplift the state to a common parent of both or try using [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)